# Angular HTML list on select put the selected value into a app wide variable and a span

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a SPA that have the following code

```
<ul id = "vers"> <span>My App</span>
    <li class="sub">
        <a href="#">Version</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="sub">
                <a href="#">V2</a>
                <ul ng-controller="V2Ctrl">
                    <li ng-repeat = "v2 in V2s"><a href="#">{{v2}}</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="sub">
                <a href="#">V3</a>
                <ul ng-controller="V3Ctrl">
                    <li ng-repeat = "v3 in V3s"><a href="#">{{v3}}</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to put the selected value into a `<span>` to display it and also store the value to a app-wide variable so that this value can be used as input for other things.

How can I do it in AngualrJs?

Update:

I am looking for the effects similar to the following:

```
var vers = "";
var link = document.getElementById("vers");
AttachEvent(link, "click", EventHandler);

function AttachEvent(element, type, handler) {
    if (element.addEventListener) element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
    else element.attachEvent("on"+type, handler);
}

function EventHandler(e) {
    alert(e.target.innerHTML);
  vers = e.target.innerHTML;
}
```

The above code actually works without a controller on the top level list.
So do I need a controller for this? If yes, When is the controller invoked?

Hope that make my question clearer.

Comment: Use a factory to store the data. Factories are singletons and stores the data as long as you don't reload the page. Otherwise you need to write a factory which stores the data in the localStorage or smth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

**HTML**

```
<ul ng-app="app" ng-controller="appController"> <span>{{value}}</span>
<li class="sub">
    <a href="#">Version</a>
    <ul>
        <li class="sub">
            <a href="#">V2</a>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat = "v2 in fruits"><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="select(v2)">{{v2}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub">
            <a href="#">V3</a>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat = "v3 in countries"><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="select(v3)">{{v3}}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li></ul>
```

**JS**

```
var App = angular.module('app', []);
App.controller('appController', function($scope, fruits, countries){
$scope.value="";
$scope.v2 = 'Apple'
$scope.v3 = 'Windows'
$scope.fruits = fruits;
$scope.countries = countries;

$scope.select = function(val){
  $scope.value = val;
}
});
App.factory('fruits', function(){
  return ['apple', 'banana', 'mango']
});
App.factory('countries', function(){
  return ['Dominican Republic', 'Panama', 'Argentina']
});
```

[Check this example working here...](https://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/njm96Luv/6/)

Comment: Hi Leo, thanks for prompt reply. I am not sure I understand your answer so I updated my question.

Comment: Hi Shawn, The example above, once you click on the item it will store the item into the `$scope.value` variable and also display it into the span... That's not what you need?

Comment: I think that's what I need:) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the communication between different angular controller is always a big theme.
I had a similar issue and there are basically two options:

- use the $rootscope **(don't use that!)**
- use a dataservice

In principle you create a service to store the global information:

```
angular.module('DataService', [])

    .service('DataService', function () {
        var service = {};
        service.topValue = "1 (default)";
        service.middleValue = "2 (default)";
        service.bottomValue;

        return service;
    })
```

I made a small project to show how it works:
https://github.com/leader80/angularjs-dataservice

and then you can just inject the dataservice wherever you need and use it with the specific controller:

```
ctrl.DataService.topValue
```

Automatically once you change it, it will globally be updated.

I hope it helps.